# How can I get a count of all previous registers of a user in a table for each time this user shows up?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Ok, so let's say I have a column like that:

```
client_calls
+------+-------+---------------------+
| id   | userId| last_call_to_client |
+------+-------+---------------------+
| 3004 |   664 | 2013-04-01          |
| 3005 |   664 | 2014-05-09          |
| 3006 |   664 | 2015-12-11          |
| 3007 |   664 | 2021-11-24          |
| 3008 |   664 | 2022-03-05          |
+------+-------+---------------------+
```

And I need this result, a table that counts how many calls a client got before the date in a specific row:

```
client_calls_so_far
+------+-------+---------------------+-----------------+
| id   | userId| last_call_to_client | calls_so_far    |
+------+-------+---------------------+-----------------+
| 3004 |   664 | 2013-04-01          | 0               |
| 3005 |   664 | 2014-05-09          | 1               |
| 3006 |   664 | 2015-12-11          | 2               |
| 3007 |   664 | 2021-11-24          | 3               |
| 3008 |   664 | 2022-03-05          | 4               |
+------+-------+---------------------+-----------------+
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example for you:

```
select *,count(last_call_to_client) over (partition by userId rows between unbounded preceding and current row) -1 as count_call
from client_calls;
```

demo : https://dbfiddle.uk/ceEDVUg-
[image]